# Returning Specific substring's pattern from given String?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, string, algorithm

I want to implement a C/C++ function that its input is an array of chars, like this:

```c
char string[]="abccccfffcccccc"
```

and then search for a specific string pattern, then return an array of chars (string) according to the last index of my searched pattern + 6 chars.

For example, lets assume I want to search on string pattern `"ab"`, so if the searched pattern is found in my input, return the substring of my input that starts from the last index of my searched pattern and end at (index + 6), so in this case the returned substring will be `"ccccff"` because the last index of `"ab"` is at `index=1`, so the returned substring will start from index 2 (the next index which it's 1+1 => at index 2) and the end of the substring will end at index 1 + 6=7 (moving 6 chars from index 1).

What I've done in my code is this:

```cpp
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str1 = "abccccfffcccccc"; // this example just for finding out if my function gives me the first index of every the specific pattern appearance
    string str2 = "ab"; %pattern that I'm searching in the given string-str1.
    int pos = 0;
    int index;
    while ((index = strstr(str1,str2)) != NULL){
        cout << "Match found at position: " << index << endl;
        cout << "Required String starts from index + 1 until the end is " << str1[str1.length()-(index)]; // % in my case it outputs and print "ccccff" because the first index of 11 is index=zero so the string should starts from index+1  
    
        pos = index + 1; //new position is from next element of index
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the wrong output. Can anyone help me to implement this in C or C++?

The substring that I'm searching for in the given string could appear more than once. This means, for example, that in the given string `"abccccfffccabcc"`, if I search for the substring `"ab"`, I need to return for each appearance of `"ab"` the required output as I explained above (assuming the size of the array is compatible to my problem, and there's no exceeded indexes errors, etc).

In addition, if the substring that I search for isn't included in the given string, then return `NULL`.

Comment: so with `000ab111ab222` searching for `ab` you want to get `['000ab', '111ab']`?

Comment: @Berto99 Based on the OP's description and attempted code, it would need to be `['111ab2']` instead, or possibly `['111ab2', '222']`

Answer (score 0):

`strstr()` returns a `char*` pointer to the found substring, not an index to the substring.  To get an index, you would have to use pointer arithmetic, eg:

```c
char *ptr = strstr(str1,str2);
if (ptr) {
    index = ptr - str1;
    ...
}
```

However, you shouldn't be using `strstr()` in C++ for this.  `std::string` has its own [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method for searching for a substring, which does return an index.  And `std::string` has a [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method for extracting a substring at a given index+length.

So, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "abccccfffcccccc";
    std::string str2 = "ab";
    std::string::size_type index, pos = 0;

    while ((index = str1.find(str2, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "Match found at position: " << index << std::endl;
        index += str2.length();
        std::cout << "String is " << str1.substr(index, 6) << std::endl;
        pos = index;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In a function, it could look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using Match = std::pair<std::string::size_type, std::string>;
using MatchVec = std::vector<Match>;

MatchVec findPattern(const std::string &str, const std::string &pattern)
{
    MatchVec vec;
    Match m;

    std::string::size_type index, pos = 0;

    while ((index = str.find(pattern, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        m.first = index;
        index += pattern.length();
        m.second = str.substr(index, 6);
        vec.push_back(m);
        pos = index;
    }

    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "abccccfffcccccc";
    std::string str2 = "ab";

    auto matches = findPattern(str1, str2);
    for(auto &match : matches) {
        std::cout << "Match found at position: " << match.first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "String is " << match.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/m9JL8n)